# Calling VBA Functions with parentheses and named arguments

Tags: excel, vba

I can call a vba function without parenthesis and use named arguments:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=file, local:=True
```

When the call is supposed to return a value, VBAs documentation states: *"To use the return value of a function, assign the function to a variable and enclose the arguments in parentheses, as shown in the following example."* [Link to docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/calling-sub-and-function-procedures#use-parentheses-when-calling-function-procedures)

I can call the function with parentheses, like so:

```
Set opened_wb = Workbooks.Open(file, , , , , , , , , , , , , True)
```

Is there a way to utilize named arguments, when calling functions with parenthesis? I find it unreadable to call a function with 10 positional arguments, especialy it 8 of them are not used.

Comment: Did you try what you have asked yourself, and what did that result in?

Comment: 'Set opened_wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=file, local:=True)'
should do the job. Its the same logic.

Comment: Turns out i missed the double colon... Sometimes it helps to open my eyes while programing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the answer right on the link you provided, just below that line you mentioned. You can indeed call them like this:

```
Set opened_wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=file, local:=True)
```